# How do i implement a authentication and authorization WEBAPI 2 .NET appication? trying JWT lib

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, token

I know this question was asked many times, but i could not find an answer i understood.
So, I'm implementing 2 APIs - one in Node.JS and the other in .NET.
In Node it was a piece of cake to add authorization and authentication but i could not get it done with .NET.

Can any of you guys point me to the right direction?
My project is a WEBAPI2 project in .NET, not MVC.
If this matters, I will build my client in React, not angularJS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OWIN for that and it's all done in your StartUp class.
See the following example.
For simplicity, I used a custom user table instead of Identity and also put all classes in StartUp class.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;
using Owin;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using TempPerson.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(TempPerson.Startup))]
namespace TempPerson
{
    public partial class Startup
    {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/login"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
                Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:62343")

            };

            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);


            var issuer = "http://localhost:62343";
            var audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
            var audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"]);

          app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityKeyProviders = new IIssuerSecurityKeyProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityKeyProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                    }

                });
        }
    }

    public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            try
            {
                context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

                         DB_PersonSpecificationsEntities db = new DB_PersonSpecificationsEntities();
               var user =  db.Users.Where(d => d.UserName == context.UserName).FirstOrDefault();
                if(user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("Error Message");
                    context.Rejected();
                    return;
                }
                var x = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher().VerifyHashedPassword(user.Password, context.Password);
               if(x.ToString() != "Success")
                {
                    context.SetError("Error Message");
                    context.Rejected();
                    return;
                }
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("JWT");

                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity,null);
                context.Validated(ticket);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "message");
            }
        }

    }

    public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private readonly string _issuer;
        public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
        {
            _issuer = issuer;
        }


        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
            }

            string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];

            string symmetricKeyAsBase64 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceSecret"];

            var keyByteArray = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(symmetricKeyAsBase64);
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(keyByteArray);
            var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
            var signingKey2 = new SigningCredentials(key, "HS256");// 

            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;

            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime,signingKey2);

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var jwt = handler.WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Key-Values required for web.config:

```
<add key="as:AudienceId" value="123e1927a3884f61abc79f7283837ee1" />
<add key="as:AudienceSecret" value="fMCdF0Qua23RV1Y-1Gq9L3cF3VmuFwV5am4faTdAfpo" />
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't have a startup class... I might sound stupid but I can't find it.

Comment: Create one in the root of your solution explorer.

Comment: Create a startup class as follows
 `public class Startup
{
   public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
   {
     //
   }
} `

Comment: @DinethCooray but what does that class do? nd where do I create it?